# How to run multiprocessing.process multiple time after every 30mins

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to login to device every 30mins to poll some data, I have multiple host to which I poll the data with multiple commands.
I have put the code in for loop however it just executes only once and does not execute for the 2nd iteration.

```
for n in range(5): ###putting loop to execute multiprocessing.Process to run multiple times
    print(f"\nStart of Round {n + 1}:")
    process_list = []
    for hostname in ipfile:
        ip = hostname.strip()    
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=connector, args=(ip, username, password))    
        process_list.append(process)
        process.start()
        time.sleep(2)
        process_alive = 1  
    while process_alive == 1:
        try:
            alive_list = []
            for p in process_list:
                if p.is_alive():
                    alive_list.append(1)
                    break
                if not p.is_alive():
                    alive_list.append(0)
            if 1 in alive_list:
                process_alive = 1
            else:
                process_alive = 0
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            for p in process_list:
                if p.is_alive():
                    p.terminate()
    print(f"\nEnd of Round {n + 1}:")
    time.sleep(30)### wait for 30mins for second iteration
```

Tried using it as a function to which I was getting error as "UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment" for process_alive

Comment: You ask sleep 30 seconds not minutes! The parameter for sleep is second.

Comment: (1) Which operating system? (2) What is the output (show it as properly formatted text in the question)? (3) What exactly happens?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you posted, then as long as `ipfile` (which you have not defined in your code) has at least one element, then the assignment `process_alive = 1` should execute at least once. But you say the loop executes once, which suggests that `process_alive` must have been defined.

But your `while process_alive == 1:` loop, which appears to be waiting for all tasks to complete, seems to be quite inefficient. You are wasting CPU cycles needlessly testing if any process is still alive. You could instead issue `join` method calls on all the processes and know that until they all return that there must be at least one process still running. I would also suggest you organize the code along the following lines. If you enter Ctrl-c at the keyboard while a run is executing, it will automatically terminate the current run and wait `TIME_BETWEEN_RUNS` seconds before starting the next run. If you then enter Ctrl-c while the program is waiting to start the next run, it will start the next run immediately:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

# For demo purposes:

ipfile = ['a', 'b', 'c']
username = 'user'
password = 'password'

#TIME_BETWEEN_RUNS = 30 * 60 # 30 minutes
# For demo purposes just wait 5 seconds between runs:
TIME_BETWEEN_RUNS = 5

def connector(ip, username, password):
    time.sleep(2)
    print('ip =', ip)

def main():
    process_list = []
    for n in range(1, 6): ###putting loop to execute multiprocessing.Process to run multiple times
        try:
            print(f"\nStart of Round {n}:")
            for hostname in ipfile:
                ip = hostname.strip()
                process = multiprocessing.Process(target=connector, args=(ip, username, password))
                process_list.append(process)
                process.start()
                time.sleep(2) # Wait 2 seconds
            # Wait until no processes are running:
            for process in process_list:
                process.join()
            print(f"\nEnd of Round {n}:")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            for process in process_list:
                if process.is_alive():
                    process.terminate()
        finally:
            process_list = []
            try:
                print(f'sleeping for {TIME_BETWEEN_RUNS} seconds')
                time.sleep(TIME_BETWEEN_RUNS)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pass # Start next run immediately

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi @Booboo, I tested the code, however it is giving the same output which I was getting before. It gives ouput for first round(iteration) but for other iteration it does not execute.
`
Start of Round 1:
Connecting to devices 
Authentication (password) successful!
Connecting to devices 
Authentication (password) successful!
>>>>>  command: show clock
>>>>>  command: show clock
Disconnecting device 
Disconnecting device 

End of Round 1:
sleeping for 5 seconds

Start of Round 2:

End of Round 2:
sleeping for 5 seconds

Start of Round 3:

End of Round 3:
`

Comment: Most of these messages are meaningless to me without your posting a minimal, reproducible example, which you still haven't posted. We need to see a *minimal* piece of code that is complete (reproducible by us) that only executes the "first round iteration".